# Dynamic cropping of image inside container

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to create a functionality that I've been trying to search for, but haven't had any luck. I want to upload an image and the image should expand to the size of the container while maintaining its width and height. If the image is bigger than the container, then only a part that covers the entire container is shown. Kind of like this JavaScript library:
[Croppie JS](https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/)

However, I haven't found this type of library in Android. How do I build something like this? I'd love some suggestions or some references.

Comment: "upload an image" -- upload it... where? "the image should expand to the size of the container" -- what container? "I haven't found this type of library in Android" -- if you are uploading to a server, what does Android have to do with this?

Comment: @CommonsWare I added an example to show the effect I'm trying to produce. If I have a container that's 300x500x...and an image that's 600x600, then this image should take up the full container, and the parts that don't should be out of view. I can move around the image to choose which parts show and which don't...exactly like in the link provided. "if you are uploading to a server, what does Android have to do with this?" -It doesn't, I only want the UI part. Users should be able to see dynamically how their image should look like cropped into that container

Comment: "I can move around the image to choose which parts show and which don't" -- OK, so, you're looking for an image-cropping library? "I haven't found this type of library in Android" -- searching for `android image cropping library` turns up lots of hits on major search engines.

Comment: You're right, there are tons of image cropping libraries...but I haven't seen one that actually dynamically shows what will be cropped in the fragment, inside a container. I mean think about you wanting to upload an image as a profile pic, you want to see which parts of your face show and how it looks like in the profile circle container. You can even zoom into your face dynamically by pinching in...all that is done inside the container

Comment: @user2896120 And if you add the word `zoom` to your search (i.e. 'pinch and zoom') you'll find additional libraries to investigate.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I'm not saying there aren't any cropping libraries. I'm saying there are no libraries of my knowledge that I've described repeatedly, that do what I'm describing. Everything is done in the container inside a fragment. I mean look at the example that I've provided. Do you know any library that does that?

Comment: @MorrisonChang most cropping libraries let you choose the image, and then crop it then and there and then you see the cropped image output. You can't recrop the image if you wish to do so without re uploading and following the same process

Comment: @user2896120 Question seems to fall under `recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic`. Note that there is a https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ which this might be on-topic with additional info like how existing libraries specifically don't work for you with images/gifs/drawings as needed, similar to projects like: https://github.com/CanHub/Android-Image-Cropper or https://github.com/CrazyOrr/ZoomCropImage but explain how those don't work for you (and do look at project issues for forks/updates).